2d top down movement physics: speed, max speed, acceleration, friction, velocity, delta
I am creating a 2d top down game and am trying to implement movement. My current approach is very simple and looks like this
movement = (-input.left + input.right, -input.up + input.down)
acceleration = movement * SPEED
velocity += acceleration * dt
velocity *= FRICTION
position += velocity

where (0<)SPEED and (0<)FRICTION(<1) are constants. It works well for a specific speed at a specific update rate, but changing the update rate (and thus delta) has great effects on the movement (large slowup/down).
I tried a similar approach that looks like this
movement = (-input.left + input.right, -input.up + input.down)
acceleration = movement * SPEED - velocity * FRICTION
velocity += acceleration * dt
position += velocity

where (0<)FRICTION but once again, at different update rates the movement was different.
I have tried different ways to implement friction/slowdown but I am not sure where I need to include delta to keep it consistent. Furthermore, I have tried clamping the updated velocity to (-MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED) before applying it to the position but that does not seem correct as it does not retain the original magnitude. I understand that I can check if its magnitude is greater than the max speed, normalise it, then scale it by the max speed but once again I am not sure where to stick in delta to keep it consistent.
How can I design a movement system that incorporates a speed (px/sec), max speed (px/sec), friction (any kind of adjustable slowdown) that behaves the same across different update rates?

It looks like some of your questions are answered here: Calculating framerate-independent values, for linear, quadratic, and exponential functions. For enforcing a max speed, I usually use this approach. Are you able to solve your problem with these existing answers? If not, try to edit your question to show how you've tried incorporating this information and where you still need help achieving your desired outcomes.
